# What is the posix regular expression for rm *?

Tags: c, regex, posix

I want to write a posix regular expression for `rm *` where there can be 1 to many spaces between `rm` and `*`. Following is the regular expression which I have come up with. I have tested it on some online posix regular expression testers but it is not working inside my program.

Regular Expression: `^rm[[:space:]]+[*]$`

```
regex_t regex;
int reti;

reti = regcomp(&regex, "^rm[[:space:]]+[*]$", 0);
if( reti ){ fprintf(stderr, "Could not compile regex\n"); exit(1); }
reti = regexec(&regex, linux_command_1, 0, NULL, 0);
if( reti == REG_NOMATCH )
{
    system(linux_command_1); 
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with "not working"? Doesn't it compile or doesn't it match strings you expect it to match?

Comment: It gets compiled fine. But it doesn't match expected strings like 'rm *'

Comment: `" rm *" "rm -rf *" "rm * " "rm *.*" "rm **" "rm ../*"` and quite a few more would beat your check though.

Comment: Yeah, Thanks for the suggestion. I would keep it in mind and design my regular expression accordingly. I was just getting to compile and run one simple regular expression with posix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't work because of the `+` modifier which would be supported in ERE.  (Refer to [Regular Expressions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap09.html) for details.)

You need to set the `cflags` to `REG_EXTENDED`, i.e. say:

```
reti = regcomp(&regex, "^rm[[:space:]]+[*]$", REG_EXTENDED);
```

Answer (score 1):

`+` is an extended regexp feature. Pass the `REG_EXTENDED` flag to `regcomp`.

Answer (score 0):

this one seems working

```
^rm\s+\*$
```